# C# (.NET) WebAPI: Show more items in the call stack

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I've been trying to debug some reference issues between a C# WebAPI project and a separate class library. For whatever reason, I can call the class library code from a console app, but if I try to call it from a WebAPI project specifically, my application fails with `FileNotFound` runtime exceptions because it can't find dependencies. I'm guessing it's some weird issue with STA threads/COM but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

When my application starts, it opens a webpage, and that webpage includes a stack trace with a list of reference exceptions. This stack trace looks like it could be super helpful as it lists in what order references weren't found, but it's really short (it only has three entries). How can I view this entire stack trace? I tried using Visual Studio's `Debug > Windows > Call Stack` window but it says that only native runtime code is running so it's not supported by the current debug engine.

How can I view more entiries from the stack trace displayed in a C# WebAPI browser window?

Comment: What is the name of the library that it can't find? (the exception will tell you) Is a DLL by that name in your `bin` folder?

Comment: @GabrielLuci The `FileNotFound` exceptions are for dependencies of the (non-executable) class library. But they only happen when that class library is referenced by a WebAPI project. A console app or WPF app can referenece it and run with no problems. The right dlls are in the right `bin` folders as far as I can tell. If I could see more entries in the stack trace, I could see exactly which dependency failed to load in which order. I just can't figure out where I can view the full stack trace that's shown by ASP .NET WebAPI

Comment: Does it show in the Event Viewer? Any unhandled exceptions should be in there.